# How to retrieve a query plan

Tags: sql, postgresql

What prefix can be added to a Postgres SQL query in order to retrieve a query plan? *

EXPLAIN

PLAN

EVALUATE

UNFOLD

Can somebody help me among these.

I am confused.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT * FROM foo;
```

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html